# change iphone project to work in both iphone and ipad

Tags: iphone, ipad

I already have an application which i have built for iphone only. I need to change it to work in both iphone and ipad.the upgrade to ipad application option in project tab of xcode is faded.. which I means I cant do that... I tried to run the project in ipad simulator but it gets automatically run in iphone simulator.

What are the proper steps to change my project to work in iphone and ipad.

Comment: Make your app Universal. Universal app will run on both iPhone and iPad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially change the build setting,ie change the Targeted Device Family field to iPhone/iPad. To write logic for iPad use "UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad" this condition.